# gem5 gets stuck at the gues OS login Page?

Tags: gem5

Gem5 gets stuck at the OS Login Page when running gem 5 in full mode.
The guest OS is Ubuntu 16.4

Either logging through m5term or running a command like the following

/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt -d /tmp/multiple__stats_omg gem5/config/example/fs.py --script configs/boot/run_some_program.rcS

Any solutions to that ?

Comment: I would recommend that you start testing this with QEMU which boots much faster to understand what Ubuntu is doing and how to change it. Interestingly, this thread says 16.04 logs in automatically on serial: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010805/disable-auto-login-on-16-04-when-connecting-via-serial-console so I'm not sure what is going on. For Buildroot, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299408/how-to-login-automatically-without-typing-the-root-username-or-password-in-build/300152